# Wokflow: Add 1 to a column when a document is uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

We are using SharePoint Enterprise 2013 On-Premises

I have a procedures library and I would like to have a column called 'Code' so when a document is uploaded a value is added to the column for example

P100-1

Then when a another document is uploaded it will get

P100-2

I am trying to replace the system we have that is currently in a file share

[image]

Comment: SharePoint can do so much more than replicating a (stupid) file share based storage. Should the numbers match with the file name/subject? Your screenshot has no 001

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "match with the filename / subject". The P100-001 etc will be a column associated with the document

Comment: So your screenshot is wrong? .. it does not show 001. Is Quality Records always 005?

Comment: The screenshot is an example of the problem we have with people missing numbers, hence moving it SharePoint to control it, no Quality Records will not always be 005, the title will always be different

The Code and document title will be separate pieces of information in SharePoint

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. If these screenshot files had been uploaded to SharePoint they would be numbered up to P100-008. What defines a 'missing' document then?

Comment: We need to assign a unique number (P100-001, P100-002 etc for example) to a document that gets uploaded SharePoint, the screenshot is what we have at the moment on a file share, users manually add the unique number to the document title, but as you have stated 001 is not there, that;s why we want to have the numbers automatically assigned to prevent any missing numbers.

We do not need the unique number attached the document title in SharePoint we want the unique number assigned in a column associated with the document